# Android: NPE: Observable.takeLast

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java2

I set up some observables like so

```
companion object {
        var isLocationToolActive: BehaviorSubject<Boolean> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(false)
        var isAoIToolActive: BehaviorSubject<Boolean> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(false)
        var pointToPosition: BehaviorSubject<GeoPoint> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(GeoPoint(0.0, 0.0))
}

init {
   pointToPosition.subscribe {  <--- Throws exception on this line
      // some code
   }

}
```

But when I try to run it it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.reactivex.Observable io.reactivex.Observable.takeLast(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit, io.reactivex.Scheduler, boolean, int)' on a null object reference
    at io.reactivex.Observable.takeLast(Observable.java:11258)
    at <the line of the code above>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried taking it out of the companion object, I tried calling onNext() before the subscribe line, but none of that solved it. I tried if the other two observables have the same issue (the ones with "false") and they do too.

EDIT: Subscribe method of pointToPosition

```
companion object {
    private var isPTPActive = false
}

init {
    pointToPosition.subscribe {
        isPTPActive = false
    }
}
```

I have also tried to just put a Log.v() in the subscribe method, this also crashes.

I tried to eliminate as many things as I possibly could, I commented out all code that was calling `pointToPosition`, I moved it outside of the `companion object` block, and as suggested I moved the subscribe function outside of init(). Like so:

```
var locationHelper = LocationBasedHelper(context, resources)
locationHelper.run()
// where run() has the pointToPosition.subscribe { } in it
```

All of these changes still result in the same error.

EDIT 2: Seems like this error happens on specific devices.
It crashes on Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 (SM-T713), but works on Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 (SM-T710). It also works on the newer Galaxy Tab A8.

Comment: have you tried taking the code from inside the init into a function and calling that instead of relying on init ?

Comment: The exception makes no sense. `pointToPosition` is a raw `BehaviorSubject` so it shouldn't have any `takeLast` applied to it at all. What is inside the `subscribe` method?

Comment: @akarnokd I have updated the question with more information

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes I have tried that. I updated the question.

Comment: Where do you have `takeLast` in your project?

Comment: @akarnokd That's the fun part, I do not use it. My entire project does not call `takeLast`. The stack trace is all I got, which sounds like subscribe is calling takeLast, but that doesnt make sense since it works on other devices. The app is unfortunately not debuggable.

Comment: In that case, sounds like a bug in the runtime of those devices (wouldn't be the first time in relation to Rx). What I'd do is to move the `BehaviorSubject` initialization into an `init` on the companion, or into the `init` of the class, or even doing an on-demand getter such as `if subject == null { subject = ... } return subject`.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you for the ideas. I tried everything you suggested, but it always ended with the same error. At this point I feel like my options are to abandon Rx or accept that some devices are broken. I also wonder if switching from rxjava2 to rxjava3 would make any difference

Comment: Switching: no way to tell if that helps. Could end up with crashes naming a different Rx method. It's up to you if you want to explore this route. Anyway, the particularity of the issue is something that is very likely unsolvable from the library's side. You could play around with the project build settings; introduce obfuscation, changing what goes into what multi-module.